# jQuery tabs tabs() - to show hide separate divs depending on tab1 & tab2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to show particular div when tab1 is selected. same as for tab2. Please give me a solution to show/hide these divs when tabs are clicked. I am not able to identify particular class or Id of these tabs in active state. What's my requirement is when tab1 is clicked I need to show `tab1` and `content1` divs

Below is link

http://jsfiddle.net/ucaxt/

Answer (score 1):

One approach, that doesn't require moving your external content into the tabs themselves, is:

```
var contents = $('div[id^="content"]').hide();
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(evt, ui) {
        var num = ui.newPanel.attr('id').replace(/\D+/g, '');
        contents.hide();
        $('#content' + num).show();
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ucaxt/3/).

This approach *does*, though, require that you append a number to the `id` of *all* the content `div` elements to be shown, in order to identify the relation between the clicked tab, the shown panel and the element *outside* of the tabs; so your HTML becomes:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="content1">
    <p>
        on click of first tab (tab1) I need to show this id as well
    </p>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="content2"> <!-- added the '2' to the id here -->
    <p>
        on click of Second tab (tab2) I need to show this id as well
    </p>
</div>
```

If you wrap the content `div` elements in an outer container, in my demo it's got the `id` of `containers`, then you can target the `div`s to show/hide slightly differently:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(evt, ui) {
        var num = ui.newPanel.attr('id').replace(/\D+/g, '');
        $('#contents > div').eq(num - 1).show().siblings().hide();
    }
});
```

And with the HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content1">
        <p>
            on click of first tab (tab1) I need to show this id as well
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="content2">
        <p>
            on click of Second tab (tab2) I need to show this id as well
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ucaxt/4/).

I've amended the above code, in response to the comment left (below) by the OP:

> [On] load of a page I need to show content div1 as well along with tab1 content.

```
function showContent(evt, ui) {
    if (!evt || !ui) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // ui.newPanel in the activate event,
        // ui.panel in the create event
        var panel = ui.newPanel || ui.panel,
            num = panel.attr('id').replace(/\D+/g, '');
        $('#contents > div').eq(num - 1).show().siblings().hide();
    }
}
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        // runs the function when the tabs are created:
        create: function(evt, ui) {
            showContent(evt, ui);
        },
        // runs the function when the tabs are activated:
        activate: function(evt, ui) {
            showContent(evt, ui);
        }
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ucaxt/6/).

Comment: Thank for your quick solution. But on load of a page I need to show content div1 as well along with tab1 content

Comment: Please help me a solution.

Comment: See the edited answer, the last code snippet should do as you need, I think.

Comment: if the question is answered, and that answer works, to your satisfaction please consider accepting the answer.